# I cannot work out the error in the script

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am very new to programming and I cannot debug my program. Whenever I run it it gives the same error:

```
return type mismatch of function f at (1)
```

My code is:

```
      real function F(x)
        implicit none
        real:: x
        F=exp(-x)-x
      end function

      program easycod
        implicit none
        real::xl,xu,xr,fu,test,xrold,fl,fr
        integer ::i
        do i=1,50
          xr=xrold
          xr=(xl+xu)/2.0
          fr =F(xr)
          fl =F(xl)
          test=fl*fr 
          IF (test>0.0) then
            xl=xr 
            fr=fl
          else if (test<0.0) then
            xu=xr 
          end if
          if (test==0.0) exit 
          print*,xr
        end do
      end program
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

First, you are getting a compiler error because you haven't declared your function `F` in your `program`:

```
program easycode
    implicit none
    real :: xl, xu, xr, fu, test, xrold, fl, fr
    real :: F                    ! <----------------- Add this line
    integer :: i
```

Then you are assigning `xr` twice, which makes the first one unnecessary. Finally, `xold`, `xl` and `xr` are not initialized and can therefore be given any value the compiler would like.